# Text Animation for Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

This is how my webpage looks:
[image]

**I want the text "Carlos Qiano" and "Lorem Ipsum" to have the same animation effect as the link:** https://neelbhavsar.me/
[image]

Note:

- For the text "Carlos Qiano", it should fade out three times after you first land on the webpage. Then, the text zooms in and out repeatedly.
- For the text "Lorem Ipsum.", it should zoom in and out repeatedly.

**Here is my HTML code that needs to be modified. I used animate.css in my code. Feel free to change it up and use any other libraries for animation.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Background Top</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
      <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Animation -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
   </head>
   <style type="text/css">
      body{
        margin-top: 53px;
      }
      .jumbotron {
        background-image: url("background1.jpg");
        text-align: center;
        height:523px;
        background-size: cover;
        margin:0 !important;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .mainText {
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 120px !important;
        margin-top: 35px; 
        color: black;
        margin: 0 0 5rem 0;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        animation-delay: 1s;
      }
      .subText {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Georgia,serif;
        font-style:italic;
        line-height: 1.6;
        color: black;
        animation-duration:2s;
        animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        animation-delay:1s;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .mainText {
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .subText {
          display: none;
        }
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <!-- //SECTION FOR PAGE TOP -->
      <section id="page-top">
         <div class="jumbotron">
            <p data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="500" class="lead mainText pulse green aos-init aos-animate" id="name">Carlos Qiano</p>
            <p data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="500" class="lead pulse lightGreen aos-init aos-animate d-md-block subText">Lorem Ipsum.<br>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
         </div>
      </section>
      <br><br><br>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          $("#name").fadeOut(750).fadeIn(750);
          $("#name").fadeOut(750).fadeIn(750);
          $("#name").fadeOut(750).fadeIn(750);
        });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to start pulse animation at start but tell if this is what you want :)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#name").fadeOut(750).fadeIn(750).fadeOut(750).fadeIn(750).fadeOut(750).fadeIn(750, function(){
    $(".subText, #name").removeClass('animate__pulse');
    // reset of pulse animation to make it sync
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".subText, #name").addClass('animate__pulse');  }, 0); 
  });
});
```

```css
body{
        margin-top: 53px;
      }
      .jumbotron {
        background-image: url("background1.jpg");
        text-align: center;
        height:523px;
        background-size: cover;
        margin:0 !important;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .mainText {
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 80px !important;
        margin-top: 35px; 
        color: black;
        margin: 0 0 5rem 0;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        animation-delay: 1s;
      }
      .subText {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Georgia,serif;
        font-style:italic;
        line-height: 1.6;
        color: black;
        animation-duration:2s;
        animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        animation-delay:1s;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .mainText {
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .subText {
          display: none;
        }
      }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
      <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
      
      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Animation -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>

      <!-- //SECTION FOR PAGE TOP -->
      <section id="page-top">
         <div class="jumbotron">
            <p data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="500" class="lead mainText green aos-init aos-animate" id="name">Carlos Qiano</p>
            <p data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="500" class="lead animate__pulse lightGreen aos-init aos-animate d-md-block subText">Lorem Ipsum.<br>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
         </div>
      </section>
      <br><br><br>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. How can I make the texts zoom in and out a bit more?

Comment: You need to copy paste the css rull for animate__pulse from animate css and add more delay